# Почему read_table обрезает предложения?

Tags: python, строки, pandas, обработка-данных, форматирование

Нужно прочесть .txt file , юзаю read_table. При чтении длинного предложения всё работает хорошо за исключением того, что оно очень сильно урезается и на месте удалённой части появляется троеточие. Это выглядит вот так:

On Wednesday, March 7, the U.S. reg...

Есть ли какой-нибудь параметр в методе read_table, который сделает чтение файла корректным?

Вот код :

```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np

path=r"C:\Users\neir0\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\textout.txt"

df=pd.read_table(path,header=None,encoding='utf-8')

date=[]
state=[]

for index , row in df.iterrows():
    x=8480
    case_1=range(0,x,3)
    case_2=range(1,x,3)
    if "date :" in str(row) :
        date.append(row)
    elif 'content :' in str(row) :
        state.append(row)
    elif 'href :' in str(row):
        continue

df=pd.DataFrame({'date':date,'content':state})
z=[]
for p in df['date']:
    z.append(p)
year=[]
month=[]
day=[]
for w in z:
    w=str(w).split('T')
    t=str(w[0]).replace('-',' ').replace('date : ','').split(' ')
    year.append(t[4])
    month.append(t[5])
    day.append(t[6])

df=pd.DataFrame({'year':year,'month':month,'day':day,'content':state})
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\neir0\Desktop\ez\bitcoin_analyzer\data\content.csv",index=False)
```

Хочу обратить внимание на возможный косяк: я преобразовываю строку файла (Series) в обычный str() для проверки условия...

Comment: Может, обрезается только вывод?

Comment: нет , я в файл записывал

Answer (score 2):

Pandas обрезает вывод длинных строк в столбцах при выводе на печать, но при записи в файл (`.to_csv()`, `to_sql()`, etc.) данные **не** обрезаются:

Демо:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['*' * 80] * 5})

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
                                                text
0  **********************************************...
1  **********************************************...
2  **********************************************...
3  **********************************************...
4  **********************************************...
```

Проверяем длину строк:

```
In [3]: df.text.str.len()
Out[3]:
0    80
1    80
2    80
3    80
4    80
Name: text, dtype: int64
```

Как настроить вывод:

```
In [4]: pd.options.display.max_colwidth=81

In [5]: pd.options.display.width=100

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
                                                                               text
0  ********************************************************************************
1  ********************************************************************************
2  ********************************************************************************
3  ********************************************************************************
4  ********************************************************************************
```

**UPDATE:**

проблема у вас в этой строке:

```
str(w[0]).replace('-',' ').replace('date : ','').split(' ')
```

при вызове str(...) вызывается метод `Series.__str__()`, который предназначен для вывода на печать - он в итоге обрезает строку.

Comment: а если я превращаю объект Series в str ? как тогда быть ?

Comment: попробуйте: `df.to_csv(filename, index=False)` и проверьте в файле

Comment: что значит "как быть"? настройки вывода действуют одинаково на DataFrame и на Series

Comment: то же самое , только без индексов

Comment: понимаешь , при превращении Series в str сохраняется обрезанная строка

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74547/discussion-between-sahar-vkusni-and-maxu).